# How to write a program that reads a .txt file that contains words with numbers in a separate column and print out the word with the biggest number?

Tags: python, sorting

I am very new to coding so this is all I have right now. I am running into problems trying to select the highest number and printing out the word that corresponds with it.

Edit: I am also supposed to write a code that also ignores the `'#'`character and anything that comes after it.

```
text = open('heroes.txt', 'r')
for line in sorted(text, key = lambda line: line.split()[1]):
    if not '#' in line:
        line.isalnum() or line == '_'
        continue
```

[This is the text file with the lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntsQX.png)

Comment: Prefer raw text over screenshot whenever applicable : data sample, code, console output, error texts etc.

Comment: you're very new to coding and trying to use lambda? i would suggest not, it's not that intuitive.

Comment: My friend was trying to help me. I'm not really sure what it means.

Comment: When in doubt, consult the documentation. Here what it says about [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off SuperStew's answer, changed to make it a little more intuitive for a beginner. Added comments.

```
text = open('heroes.txt', 'r')

# Empty dictionary
data = {}

# For every line in the file...
for line in text.readlines():
    # skip if line starts with #
    if line.startswith('#'):
        continue

    # Split the name into two parts, hero name and hero power.
    row = line.split()

    # Map row data to dictionary. Hero name will be key, hero power will be value.
    data[row[0]] = row[1]

# Remember to close the file
text.close()

# For every key value pair in data...
for k,v in data.items():
    # See if value is the max value. If so, print it.
    if v==max(data.values()):
        print(k)
```

Useful links:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: This was a lot easier for me to understand. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

this might do the trick

```
text = open('heroes.txt', 'r')
data={}
for line in text.readlines():
    if line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    d_l=line.split()
    d_l=[[x.strip() for x in y] for y in d_l]
    data[d_l[0]]= d_l[1]

text.close() #remember to close file

for k,v in data.items():
    if v==max(data.values()):
        print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!